# How to download OSX on laptop?

Tags: windows, macos, laptop

<s>I am planning to install OSX on my laptop . I read **unibeast** method to install OSX.</s>

Starting steps are:

1. Open Mac App Store
2. Log in with your Apple ID
3. Download OS X El Capitan

---

I want to purchase retail copy of OSX, or if Apple allows I can purchase a downloadable copy of OSX. I am not sure if either is possible.

I google "retail copy of OSX" and I got this link:
http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard

I am not sure if I will be able to download OSX after paying. If they will give me a link to download from Mac Store then it will be useless. It also says **Available for pickup** :
*Order today, delivers: Mon Nov 30 - Fastest | Tue Dec 1 - Free*

What is store pickup? Is it DVD or some redeemable code?

Comment: Hackintosh questions are a specific class of questions that arn't really allowed here. See http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed for more details.

Comment: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2/can-one-ask-hackintosh-questions-on-ask-different      And my question is about **legally**  obtaining/downloading OSX .  I am not asking any torrent link.

Comment: Is it an Apple laptop (i.e. some version of MacBook)? If not, installing OS X on it is a violation of the license, and **not** legal.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal The rules on AD and SU are different. I'm pretty sure that even if "getting OS X to install on non apple hardware" wasn't in the spirit and letter of the reasons given in that meta.su post, it would be closed as a product/service recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can buy a DVD anymore. You've linked to a very old version (10.6) while you need 10.11.

I've googled around and it looks like most of the hacktosh guides say you already need a mac to download OSX Installer (how convenient!). What you can do is download a pre-made VMware OSX Image from bitorrent and use it to run OSX and download El Capitan from there.

Or, alternatively, you can just show up at bestbuy or similar store and download it on of their Demo mac Laptops, and copy it to a USB Stick. Start the download, come back later to copy the installer to your stick.